# clearFocus() on SearchView onQueryTextChange

Tags: java, android

just a quick question, I'm using a Search View in a fragment and I have this code:

```
 mySearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                ticketmasterApiRequest(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), adapter, c,s);
                mySearch.clearFocus();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
               if(!StringUtils.isNotBlank(s)){
                   ticketmasterApiRequest(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), adapter, c,"");
                   mySearch.clearFocus();
               }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

The `onQueryTextSubmit` method works exactly how it meant to, it sends away the api request and then clears the request. The problem is that `onQueryTextChange` doesn't work the proper way. The way it should work is that when user hits the `x` button on the searchview then the api sends a call and the focus is cleared, but what happens is that the api call is made but the focus still stays on the search view. Any ideas how I could fix it?

Comment: You are clearing the focus on empty search . `!StringUtils.isNotBlank(s)` evaluates to `true` when the search is blank.

Comment: Yes I know it, when the search is empty it should lose the focus on the search widget but that doesn't happen. The focus is still on it